# Using present in UIViewController properly

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, closures

I encounter the problem that I cannot present a dynamic UIViewController in my class using "self". It tells me "Value of type '(LoginScreenVC) -> () -> (LoginScreenVC)' has no member 'view'".

It would work using a closure like e.g. `if let loginScreen = UIStoryBoard ...`, but since the UIViewController to switch to is dynamic, I cannot cast it to a specific UIViewController.

is there any other way to present the ViewController?

This is my code:

**SWIFT 4.2 / XCode 10.1**

```
import UIKit

class LoginScreenVC: UIViewController {
    let myTokenHandler = TokenHandler()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Login button pressed")

        let usernameInputField = self.view.viewWithTag(6548) as! UITextField
        let passwordInputField = self.view.viewWithTag(6549) as! UITextField

        userInput = usernameInputField.text!
        passInput = passwordInputField.text!

        // call completion handler
        requestToken(success: handlerBlock)

    }
    // completion handler step 1: request token and get redirect string to switch screen
    func requestToken(success: (String) -> Void) {
        let requestResult = myTokenHandler.requestToken(password: passInput, username: userInput)
        success(requestResult)
    }

    // completion handler step 2: use redirect string to switch screen
    let handlerBlock: (String) -> Void = { redirect in
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loginScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: redirect)
            self.present(loginScreen, animated: true, completion: nil) //Value of type '(LoginScreenVC) -> () -> (LoginScreenVC)' has no member 'view'
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what `self` could mean in the context of an isolated anonymous function. Why are you using an anonymous function here at all? A method will do.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to rearrange my code to work? I thought the issue is that I cannot use "present" in UIViewController.

Comment: Of course you can. It is a UIViewController instance method. But `self` here is not a UIViewController instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying:

```
let handlerBlock: (String) -> Void = { redirect in
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: redirect)
    self.present(loginScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is that you are using the term `self` in a context where there is no `self`. (Well, there is a `self`, but it isn't what you think.) `present` is a UIViewController instance method, so `self` needs to be a UIViewController instance; and in this context, it isn't.

I can think of half a dozen ways to express the thing you're trying to express, but the simplest would probably be to rewrite that as:

```
func handlerBlock(_ redirect:String) -> Void {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: redirect)
    self.present(loginScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now `handlerBlock` is an *instance method*, and `self` is meaningful — it is the instance, which is just what you want. The rest of your code is unchanged, because the bare name `handlerBlock` in the expression `requestToken(success: handlerBlock)` is a function name, just as before.

Comment: Thanks! Can you just briefly tell me what " _ " stands for in the parameter?